# Android Firebase Query over elements with a list inside

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a JSON structure of *interests* with a list of users who selected it like that:

```
{
  "-k1234" : {
    "name" : "Biking",
    "users" : {
      "jX0XxPWKUScLBkCRfpoRNJG0n3P2" : true
    }
  },
  "-k1235" : {
    "name" : "Cooking",
    "users" : {
      "5Y17UfNRWxR6mx8j6MWKQQbTTWE3" : true,
      "jX0XxPWKUScLBkCRfpoRNJG0n3P2" : true
    }
  },
  "-k1236" : {
    "name" : "Walking",
    "users" : {
      "5Y17UfNRWxR6mx8j6MWKQQbTTWE3" : true,
      "PKozrktlSaPPLZ2FRxHOP7JkZdO2" : true
    }
  },
  "-k1237" : {
    "name" : "Yoga",
    "users" : {
      "5Y17UfNRWxR6mx8j6MWKQQbTTWE3" : true,
      "jX0XxPWKUScLBkCRfpoRNJG0n3P2" : true
    }
  },
  "-k1238" : {
    "name" : "Reading",
    "users" : {
      "5Y17UfNRWxR6mx8j6MWKQQbTTWE3" : true,
      "jX0XxPWKUScLBkCRfpoRNJG0n3P2" : true
    }
  }
}
```

Every user has a section with interests, like this:

```
{
  "-5Y17UfNRWxR6mx8j6MWKQQbTTWE3" : {
    "interests" : {
      "-k1235" : true,
      "-k1236" : true,
      "-k1237" : true,
      "-k1238" : true
    }
  }
}
```

If I make a query which filter by name is easy:

```
Query query = databaseReference.child(INTERESTS).orderByChild("name").equalTo("Biking");
```

But I don't know how to make a query which filter which interests are NOT selected for a given user e.g. if the user is `"5Y17UfNRWxR6mx8j6MWKQQbTTWE3"` the query should return a `datasnapshot` object with the *"Biking"* element

```
"-k1234" : {
    "name" : "Biking",
    "users" : {
      "jX0XxPWKUScLBkCRfpoRNJG0n3P2" : true
    }
```

Is there any way to make this? or should I change the JSON data model?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to do that. First of all you need to create for each user a new section named `INTERESTS`. In this section will need to add all the interests. You will achieve this, in the same way you did for `users` in `INTERESTS`. Let's say for the `jX0XxPWKUScLBkCRfpoRNJG0n3P2` user you'll have `"Biking": true`, `"Yoga": true`, `"Cooking": false`. In this way you can filter the interest or noniterest of each user. Hope it helps.

Comment: Every user has a section with interests. I updated the question, but I don't know how to make the query itself.

Comment: To know which interestes are not selected, you need to find those interests that have the value of `false`. Just put the `reference` on the desired user like this: `databaseReference.child(USERS).child(userId).child(interests);` and add a `addChildEventListener` to see which interests is set to `false`.

Comment: I'm structuring the data like in the doc reference: [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#fanout) For a given key reference (for user or interest) the value always will be `true`, in another case the key don't exist. So I cannot see interests set to `false`. In your solution, you are filtering when the response is received and I'm trying to know if it's possible to filter on the server side.

Comment: Than you'll have to do something like this. Create a query to gather all interests from you database. Add them as a String into an `ArrayList<String>`. Than find all the interests of a single user and compare with those from the ArrayList. If the user interest exists in the ArrayList remove them. The remaining interests are those that you are looking for.

Comment: Is there everything ok?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do, if you want this logic to be server-side (and to enlight the load on the client side) is to create a firebase function that does what @5246885 suggests.